# Android Activity : Periodically updates both activity text from same data source

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, timertask

I have 2 Activities, i) **MainActivity** ii)**FavoriteActivity** and a non-activity class **RadioService**. Both Activity hava a identical method - **notifyShowBar()**, it shows a text bar defined in **showbar.xml@layout**.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notifyShowBar();
}
public void notifyShowBar() {
....
    textView.setText(revs.getMeta());
....
}
.....
```

FavoriteActivity.java

```
public class FavoriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notifyShowBar();
}
public void notifyShowBar() {
....
    textView.setText(revs.getMeta());
....
}
.....
```

Now when an activity calls RadioService, it creates a timertask, then it fetch info from server periodically,  and shows bar in parent activity. So the bar shows updated info in every 15 seconds.

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            updateMeta();
            ....
    }

    public void updateMeta() {
    timerAsync = new Timer();
    timerTaskAsync = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    // get and set meta data here and then call createShowBar
                    createShowBar();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timerAsync.schedule(timerTaskAsync, 0, 15000);
    }

    private void createShowBar() {
    if (RadioService.inwhich == 2) {
        ((FavoriteActivity) context).notifyShowBar();
    } else {
        ((MainActivity) context).notifyShowBar();
    }
    }
.....
}
```

Problem is, if I  execute a button in MainActivity which calls RadioService, it shows bar and updates there periodically. But when I browse to FavoriteActivity, it shows bar but don't update periodically. How can I make it happen for both activity? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can register one with an intent filter and then it will receive intents sent with [sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)). If you only want to update while the app is visible, register the receiver `onStart` and unregister `onStop`.

```
public class FavoriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "Something unique";

    private static final IntentFilter FILTER = new IntentFilter(ACTION_UPDATE);

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do your thing
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(receiver, FILTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Send a broadcast with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE);
// add data to intent
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also, look at [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) on a more secure way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. User can init RadioService from FavoriteActivity also! Then  RadioService creates a timertask and start updating bar on FavoriteActivity periodically. So no periodic updates on MainActivity. It a vice-versa situation. What to do?

Comment: A broadcast is kind of a fire-and-forget thing. You send one, and someone might receive it, if they're listening. You can have both activities listening, one of them or neither.

Answer (score 5):

That can be done with the simple inheritance rule. 
Create `abstract BaseActivity` with an abstract method `notifyShowBar` which extends the `AppCompatActivity`. 
Use `MainActivity` & `FavoriteActivity` as child classes of `BaseActivity`. 
Since due to the rule of abstraction, the `notifyShowBar` method would have to be implemented  in `MainActivity`  & `FavoriteActivity`, so whenever you call `notifyShowBar` in `BaseActivity` it will call the same in the child classes

Comment: can you please explain with base activity code? Sorry for my novice english. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the paste. I tried it, it's showing text bar as usual in every activity but only updating where it's created. So back to original problem. For example if I create this radioservice from favoriteactivity, it only periodically updates on favoriteactivity, not in main activity page. Here is my updated version of code : http://pastebin.com/JmNthAkp

Comment: It is not updating because favoriteactivity and mainactivity has different references in memory. Try  to create radionservice in BaseActivity. so radioService Object can be use in favoriteactivity and mainactivity since they are child class of BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

For my app's similar problem I used a Service independent of activities + [Square's Otto bus](https://github.com/square/otto). The Service posts various events into the Bus, activities subscribe to this bus instance and event types and do corresponding actions.